# Ceph erasure coding when restart all server incomplete pgs

Tags: linux, cloud, storage, hosting, ceph

i have a 7 server

Server1:mon,mgr,mds

Server 2:mon,mgr,mds

Server3:mon,mgr,mds

Server4:osd.0,osd.1

Server5:osd.2,osd.3

Server6osd.4,osd.5

Server7:mon,mgr,mds

each osd size 4T

and :

ceph osd tree

ID CLASS WEIGHT   TYPE NAME           STATUS REWEIGHT PRI-AFF

-1       21.83098 root default

-3        7.27699     host cephnode01

0   hdd  3.63899         osd.0           up  1.00000 1.00000

1   hdd  3.63899         osd.1           up  1.00000 1.00000

-5        7.27699     host cephnode02

2   hdd  3.63899         osd.2           up  1.00000 1.00000

3   hdd  3.63899         osd.3           up  1.00000 1.00000

-7        7.27699     host cephnode03

4   hdd  3.63899         osd.4           up  1.00000 1.00000

5   hdd  3.63899         osd.5           up  1.00000 1.00000

Every 2.0s: ceph -s

Tue Aug 14 09:52:47 2018

cluster:

```
id:     6b28cabd-b94a-4a74-8d9e-00b8c9a61de4

health: HEALTH_WARN

        Reduced data availability: 128 pgs inactive, 128 pgs incomplete
```

services:

```
mon: 5 daemons, quorum
```

cephnode01,cephmon01,cephnode02,cephnode03,cephmon03

```
mgr: cephmds01(active), standbys: cephmon03, cephmon02, cephmon01

mds: cephfs-1/1/1 up  {0=cephmon03=up:active}, 3 up:standby

osd: 6 osds: 6 up, 6 in
```

data:

```
pools:   2 pools, 256 pgs

objects: 279  objects, 1.0 GiB

usage:   8.1 GiB used, 22 TiB / 22 TiB avail

pgs:     50.000% pgs not active

         128 incomplete

         128 active+clean
```

During power failure

health: HEALTH_WARN

```
        Reduced data availability: 128 pgs inactive, 128 pgs incomplete
```

when i restart all servers Loss of all data and i must remove pool and 
recreate pool

below erorr displayed

health: HEALTH_WARN

```
        Reduced data availability: 128 pgs inactive, 128 pgs incomplete
```

when i change crush map #rule from host  to osd then health ok.

but i need host .

i used blow command for create pool .

i used erasure coding .

ceph osd pool create ECtemppool 128  128  erasure default

ceph osd erasure-code-profile set default  crush-failure-domain=osd  crush-

root=default  k=4 m=2 --force

rados -p ECtemppool ls

ceph osd pool create cephfs_metadata 128

ceph osd pool set ECtemppool allow_ec_overwrites true

ceph fs new cephfs cephfs_metadata ECtemppool

best regards

Comment: who can help me about this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i want a problem:
below command is work!! :

ceph osd erasure-code-profile set EC-temp-pool

ceph osd erasure-code-profile set EC-temp-pool ruleset-failure-domain=host 
k=4 m=2 --force

ceph osd pool create ECtemppool 128 128 erasure EC-temp-pool

ceph osd pool create cephfs_metadata 128

ceph osd pool set ECtemppool allow_ec_overwrites true

ceph fs new cephfs cephfs_metadata ECtemppool